# Save/recover router state in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

When user reaches a route in my application, which is protected by special guard, I'm redirecting him to a sign-in route, in order to perform authentication.

However, after successful authentication I wan't to redirect her back to a route she was initially reaching.

**How do I preserve intermediate routing state in Angular and then redirect to it?**

By routing state I mean the following:

- The route itself, i.e. path
- All query-string parameters
- A hash string

Answer (score 4):

After playing with the router a bit, I've finally managed to implement the solution I wanted. I'm going to share it here with you.

So here's the implementation of `IntermediateNavigationService`:

```typescript
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {NavigationCancel, NavigationEnd, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class IntermediateNavigationService {

  private savedUrl: string;
  private routerSubscription: Subscription;


  constructor (private router: Router) {
  }


  startWatch () {
    this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
      .subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
          // Saving URL from canceled route.
          this.saveUrl(event.url);
        } else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          // If user navigates away from sign-in page, clearing saved URL.
          if (!event.url.match(/^\/sign-in/)) {
            if (this.hasSavedUrl()) {
              this.clearSavedUrl();
            }
          }
        }
      })
    ;
  }

  stopWatch () {
    this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  saveUrl (url: string) {
    this.savedUrl = url;
  }

  hasSavedUrl () {
    return !!this.savedUrl;
  }

  getSavedUrl () {
    return this.savedUrl;
  }

  clearSavedUrl () {
    this.savedUrl = null;
  }

  goToSavedUrl (): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.router.navigateByUrl(this.savedUrl).then(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.clearSavedUrl();
      }
      return result;
    });
  }

}
```

The idea behind this service is pretty simple. When activated by `startWatch()` method (you should do it as early as possible in application lifecycle, for example in AppComponent constructor), it starts to monitor router events specifically filtering the `NavigationCancel` and `NavigationEnd` events.

- When `NavigationCancel` happens, it means, that our authentication route guard prevented the navigation to a target route. Therefore we are saving the skipped URL inside of the service private variable.
- When `NavigationEnd` happens, we check if user navigated away from our sign-in route. In this case we are no longer interested in preserving the saved URL, so we are clearing it. Otherwise it could lead to strange behavior, when user is redirected to URL he is no longer interested in.

After successful sign-in, we should just issue this code:

```typescript
if (this.intermediateNavigationService.hasSavedUrl()) {
  this.intermediateNavigationService.goToSavedUrl();
} else {
  this.navigationService.redirectAfterSignIn();
}
```

Is short: we just checking if there is a saved URL, then we navigating to it, if not redirecting to the default one.

And if you are no longer interested in monitoring the state at some point, just call to `stopWatch()` in order to cancel the router events subscription. It could be done after successful sign-in actually to preserve resources (if you are not going to use this service for similar behavior which is not related to authentication of course).

And there is no need to call `startWatch()` if user is already authenticated.

Here's how your `AppComponent` could look like:

```typescript
import {Component as NgComponent} from '@angular/core';

import {AuthenticationStateService} from './authentication/authentication-state.service';
import {IntermediateNavigationService} from './services/intermediate-navigation.service';


@NgComponent({})
export class MyAppComponent {

  constructor (
    private authenticationStateService: AuthenticationStateService,
    private intermediateNavigationService: IntermediateNavigationService
  ) {

    // Enabling intermediate URL handling.
    if (!this.authenticationStateService.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.intermediateNavigationService.startWatch();
    }

    // Listening for authentication event.
    this.authenticationStateService.onAuthenticated().subscribe(() => {
      this.intermediateNavigationService.stopWatch()
    });

  }

}
```

I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a service.

Here is a sample service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { IUser } from './user';
import { MessageService } from '../messages/message.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    currentUser: IUser;
    redirectUrl: string;

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

    isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return !!this.currentUser;
    }

    login(userName: string, password: string): void {
        if (!userName || !password) {
            this.messageService.addMessage('Please enter your userName and password');
            return;
        }
        if (userName === 'admin') {
            this.currentUser = {
                id: 1,
                userName: userName,
                isAdmin: true
            };
            this.messageService.addMessage('Admin login');
            return;
        }
        this.currentUser = {
            id: 2,
            userName: userName,
            isAdmin: false
        };
        this.messageService.addMessage(`User: ${this.currentUser.userName} logged in`);
    }

    logout(): void {
        this.currentUser = null;
    }
}
```

The full code is here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

But if you cannot find it ... here is the login component code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './app/user/login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
    errorMessage: string;
    pageTitle = 'Log In';

    constructor(private authService: AuthService,
                private router: Router) { }

    login(loginForm: NgForm) {
        if (loginForm && loginForm.valid) {
            let userName = loginForm.form.value.userName;
            let password = loginForm.form.value.password;
            this.authService.login(userName, password);

            if (this.authService.redirectUrl) {
                this.router.navigateByUrl(this.authService.redirectUrl);
            } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/products']);
            }
        } else {
            this.errorMessage = 'Please enter a user name and password.';
        };
    }
}
```

And the auth guard service to be complete:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router, Route,
         CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export  class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad {

constructor(private authService: AuthService,
            private router: Router) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log('In canActivate: ' + state.url);
    return this.checkLoggedIn(state.url);
}

canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log('In canActivateChild: ' + state.url);
    return this.checkLoggedIn(state.url);
}

canLoad(route: Route): boolean {
    console.log('In canLoad: ' + route.path);
    return this.checkLoggedIn(route.path);
}

checkLoggedIn(url: string): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
        return true;
    }

    // Retain the attempted URL for redirection
    this.authService.redirectUrl = url;
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Hello Deborah! Thank you for your answer. However, I'm more interested in the part where you get the current URL from the router and where you actually redirect back to it after sign-in. Both those parts are missing from your answer.

Comment: I provided a link to the full source code ... but if you can't find it ... I added the login component code to my answer above.